# Jasper Report - Format Crosstab

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

From a query, I get this data (simplified):

```
Referring Date  Name    Budget
2017-01        JACK     100
2017-01        JOHN     200
2017-01        SMITH    150
2017-02        JACK      50
2017-02        SMITH    200
2017-03        JOHN     300
2017-03        SMITH    200
2017-03        JENNY    150
```

I need a crosstab to organize budget on columns and referring-date and name on rows.

Using Jasper Wizard, I got this:

[image: Generated]

As you see, Referring Date is put in a Rowspan.

Unfortunally, Im requested to build something like this:

[image]

I've tried to modify Crosstab but when I try to move Referring Date above Name (companyName in my case) I got the error because Im "invading" company section.

[image]

Is there a solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Yes its  possible. Don't use Cross tab. Learn and use report Group. Create group on "referring date".

For Total create a variable of data type same as $F{budget}.Set the Calculation to 'Sum', the Reset Type to 'Group' (and pick the appropriate group from the dropdown), set the variable expression to $F{budget}.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but crosstab is required to put rows values into columns. In my - maybe too simplified - example, I put only one column (budget) but I my report I have multiple columns.

Comment: @MrMime How you solved this challenge, if you could mention it?

Comment: @MrMime Apologies for late reply. But i could see that you are using rows as is. not in cross tab way.As correctly said by you cross tab is required to put rows into columns. However your example isn't putting rows in columns.